# In Delphi Rio (10.3.3) fdQuery does not correctly translate conditional function 'iif' when a macro is NULL

Tags: delphi, macros, firedac

I have the following SQL command to run a query with a `TFDQuery` using PostgreSQL as the database:

```
fdqr.SQL.Text: = 
  'select * from (values (current_date-1), (current_date), (current_date + 1)) as t (datetest) ' +
  '{iif (! Datevalue, where datetest =! Datevalue)}';
```

When I used the `Clear` method to clear the macro value, I expected the script to be interpreted so that the filter would be eliminated, but it wasn't.

```
fdqr.MacroByName('datevalue').Clear;
fdqr.Open;
```

Resulting database log:

```sql
select * from (values(current_date-1), (current_date), (current_date+1)) as t(datetest) 
where datetest = NULL
```

However, if you include an assignment via `AsRaw`, it works as expected, even if the previous value was `''` (empty string) and `IsNull` is `True`.

```
fdqr.MacroByName('datevalue').Clear;
{ at this point IsNull = True and AsRaw is '' }
fdqr.MacroByName('datevalue').AsRaw := '';
fdqr.Open;
```

Resulting database log:

```sql
select * from (values(current_date-1), (current_date), (current_date+1)) as t(datetest)
```

Is this a FireDAC bug or a [feature](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomCommand.Macros) that I don't understand correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to apply substitution of `{IIF(…)}` or `{IF}…{FI}` based on a macro variable, the variable value must not be empty. That is what documentation for [Conditional Substitution](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Conditional_Substitution) says. It literally means that the substitution is applied if the macro variable expands to a non-empty string. This fact can be verified by inspecting FireDAC source code, specifically method `TFDPhysConnectionMetadata.TranslateEscapeSequence` in unit `FireDAC.Phys.Meta`. In case for `eskIF` you can find:

```
s := Trim(ASeq.FArgs[0]);
…
else if s <> '' then
  Result := 'True';
```

Let's see what happens when you `Clear` the macro variable. Its `Value` is set to `Null` and its `DataType` is set to `mdUnknown`. In this case the variable is expanded to `NULL` literal by the preprocessor, which is not an empty string. The value of `AsRaw` is irrelevant, because preprocessor uses [`SQL`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDMacro.SQL) property for substitution.

There seems to be no other way to expand macro variable to an empty string than setting `AsRaw := ''`. In this case its `DataType` is set to `mdRaw` and the value `SQL` property is equal to `AsRaw`.

I'm not sure whether this behaviour is a bug or feature, but changing it could break exiting code bases, so I don't expect this to be ever fixed. I'd rather say that it eventually became a feature.

Apart from the above, you can avoid macros by using simple parameters:

```sql
select * from (values(current_date-1), (current_date), (current_date+1)) as t(datetest) 
where :Datevalue is null or datetest = :Datevalue
```

This way you can clear or set the value of `Datevalue` parameter as you would expect:

```
{ to bind null value }
fdqr.ParamByName('Datevalue').Clear;
{ to bind some value }
fdqr.ParamByName('Datevalue').AsDate := Today;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed clarification. However, I noticed that in my tests that after `Clear` (Macro or Parameter), the type was not changed to `mdUnknown`.
About the suggestion to "use simple parameters", in my case it would not be an option because I need that in some scenarios there is no filter and using your suggestion (... where: Datevalue is null or datetest =: Datevalue), it is an interesting alternative, although I prefer the iif to make the final SQL cleaner.

Comment: @AnselmoMS Implementation of `TFDMacro.Clear` is pretty simple - it just calls `SetData(Null, mdUnknown);`. There are some edge cases when this method doesn't change `DataType` thanks to its **extremely ugly** implementation (it is worth checking it out for some laughs). Basically the method refuses to change data type to `mdUnknown` if the original value was equal to `Null`. This equality test depends on whole bunch of global variables - see [`NullEqualityRule`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.NullEqualityRule) & friends.